# HTML & PHP - included page is messed up as <a> tag is in the code ( IE9 )

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, include, internet-explorer-9

i know, it's a really stupid question XD

so, i've a simple index.php:

```
<html>
...
<div id="div_page">

<?php
    if( !empty($_GET["page"]) ) {
        if( $_GET["page"] == "1" ) {
            include("./page/1.php");
        } else { if( $_GET["page"] == "2" ) {
            include("./page/2.php");
        } else { if( $_GET["page"] == "3" ) {
            if( !empty($_GET["site"]) ) {
                if( $_GET["site"] == "1" ) {
                    include("./page/3.1.php");
                } else { if( $_GET["site"] == "2" ) {
                    include("./page/3.2.php");
                }}
            } else {
                include("./page/3.0.php");    // problem
            }
        } else { if( $_GET["page"] == "4" ) {
            include("./page/4.php");
        } else { if( $_GET["page"] == "5" ) {
            include("./page/5.php");
        } else { if( $_GET["page"] == "6" ) {
            include("./page/6.php");
        }}}}}}
        include("footer.php");
    } else {
        header("Location: ./index.php?page=1");
    }
?>

</div>
...
<html>
```

and a simple css:

```
#div_page {
    position:absolute;
    top:195px; right:0px; left:250px;
    min-width:500px; min-height:500px;
    padding:25px;
}
```

everything is working fine, till i add a Link-Tag [a] inside any page ( 1.php, 3.0.php ...a.s.o.)

as i do this, the page is shown up totally messed up in IE9 :/

screenshot -> http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/20/unbenanntqii.png/

why is this happening ?
any known issues / solutions ?

thx 4 any help.

g.r.

**EDIT:**

the code of 3.0.php is just like this:

```
<h1>Page 3</h1>
<p>Für Arbeitnehmer: <a href="./index.php?page=3&site=1">Site 1</a></p>
<p>Für Arbeitgeber: <a href="./index.php?page=3&site=1">Site 2</a></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var page = 3;
</script>
```

Comment: Is it only "3.0.php" that is causing issues ?

Comment: Please post the code of an included file which is causing problems -- it's *that* code which is the issue, not your "containing" code.

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierBourgeois : doesn't matter what i'm including, the error happens 4 all <page>.php.

Comment: this is not an answer to your problem, but I'd use a switch instead of if else http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php, it'll help make the code more readable.

Comment: +1 for the switch and yes, please post the content of your php page.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: done. i've edited... this is the full 3.0.php up there

Comment: guys, i've allready edited the post....

Comment: @Brad : i know that it's much cleaner with a switch, but this is just a shorten code, so i NEED the if statements 4 other things that i'll add later...

Comment: Could you provide a link to your site? The tiny snippet of HTML output you have provided is not the problem by itself.

Comment: @MrLister: i could put it temporarily on a server cuz my local server isn't online. but if u want, i could also put all the files in a .zip archive...

Comment: ...so u can also see the full php code.

Comment: You might need to add some html code at the top... such as the usual `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>`

Comment: doesn't matter, it's already insite the index.php

Comment: I've uploaded the full website in a zip. pancakes 4 the one who finds the problem :D -> http://acid.chdustar.com/page.zip

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like you are not closing your `<a>` tag correctly and IE9, which is stricter about these things, has problems in rendering the page while FF and chrome close the tag for you

Comment: I concur: the included file is ok, so it's probably something in the `...` part of the code -- almost certainly an unclosed element.

Comment: trying it without `p` is just the same. if u look to the image, u can see that the textflow is correct, just till "site 1", everything after "Für arbeitnehmer:" ( sry 4 the german text ) is just pushed to the top again, and no more insite the textflow...

Comment: unfortunately there is no unclosed tag...

i'll upload the full code in a zip file 4 those who want to debug enerything ^^

Answer (score -1):

Sorry if this doesn't help to your original problem but you could refine you logic and code readability a little bit. This is what it looks like using more lines than in you original post. Take a look at the comments.

```
<?php
if( !empty($_GET["page"]) ) {
    if( $_GET["page"] == "1" ) {
        include("./page/1.php");
    } 
        else { 
            if( $_GET["page"] == "2" ) {
                include("./page/2.php");
            }
        else { 
            //opening if, closing much later
            if( $_GET["page"] == "3" ) {

            //opening if, closing much later
            if( !empty($_GET["site"]) ) {

            if( $_GET["site"] == "1" ) {
                include("./page/3.1.php");
            } 

                else { 
                    if( $_GET["site"] == "2" ) {
                        include("./page/3.2.php");
                    }
                }
        } 
            else {
                include("./page/3.0.php");    // problem
            }
        } 

        //why not use elseif or plain if?
        else { 
            if( $_GET["page"] == "4" ) {
                include("./page/4.php");
            } 
        //why not use elseif or plain if?
        else { 
            if( $_GET["page"] == "5" ) {
                include("./page/5.php");
            } 
        else { 
            if( $_GET["page"] == "6" ) {
                include("./page/6.php");
            }
        }

    }}}}//two ending ifs and two elses?

    include("footer.php");
} 
    else {
        header("Location: ./index.php?page=1");
    }
?>
```

For me this is almost impossible to understand. If you don't want to use a `switch` statement, you still can simplify code below a lot by using plain `if` statements or `elseif`s. I don't see any particular reason for the two opening `if`s and `else`s that end in the end of the script: you have just two `GET` variables in use.

You can also combine conditions. Why use the following?

```
if( !empty($_GET["page"]) ) {
    if( $_GET["page"] == "1" ) {
```

When you can use:

```
if( !empty($_GET["page"]) && $_GET["page"] == "1") {
```

One opening `if` is better than one...

EDIT: Since the negative vote I'll just make things better or worse. Might help readability or not. I guess we all have our ways of reading and writing code...

This is what came to my mind an hour ago. Why check for every possible number if the code below works? (Haven't tested it, so I don't know.)

```
$getPage = $_GET['page'];
$getSite = $_GET['site'];

if (isset($getPage) && isset($getSite)){
  include("./page/$getPage.$getSite.php");
}
    elseif (isset($getPage) && !isset($getSite)){
      include("./page/$getPage.php");
    }
      else {
        header("Location: ./index.php?page=1");
      }
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, and `switch` has already been mentioned.

Comment: well, 4 me it's much easyer to read the code my way...
and as i said, i've set the code with there many if's, cuz i need to put more code inside later...

and the last one, i didn't put the 2 conditions in one else, cuz i would have to write for every "if page = 1 / 2 / 3 / 4... " also the "if !empty"... that would be 6 times "if !empty"...

Comment: @Ace Good answer and I now understand your writing better after looking at it for a bit longer. Amount of closing brackets in the end of the script threw me away at first but they are indeed in good order. Is it possible reduce code and to use the `GET` variable as a variable? Like: `$myGet=$_GET['whatever']`; Then you could use: `if (!empty($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == $myGet) { header("Location: ./index.php?page=$myGet")}`. If that works it reduces a lot of code. If it doesn't, sorry again.

Comment: @Andrew Yes I know the `switch` was already mentioned. That's why I only mentioned it briefly. I have seen many similar answers in different threads repeating the same thing and I saw no reason not to repeat that one suggested improvement. I do agree my answer wasn't very helpful but I wouldn't say that it wasn't an answer at all. Sorry for the inconvenience. I was merely trying to offer a way to shorten the code and lessen the amount of opening `if` statements.

Comment: well, i think we all r concentrating on php way too much...
i've put the full code in a zip file.

acid.chdustar.com/page.zip

i dont think that it's a php problem, or even an unclosed tad or something..., i think we should concentrate more on CSS...

just look in the zip for ./main.css

the whole page is a litle bit complicated because of it's layout.